# Is there a way to install or remove the lc++ compiler option in c++ Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I was trying to build a Hello World console project in C++ Xcode, but when I try to build the project with Xcode, I get this:

```
ld: library not found for -lc++
```

I haven't edited any of the settings, and my code is simple 'hello world', is there a way to fix this?